# ColdFusion Hardlink vs SoftLink traversal searching for Application.cfc (Solaris)

Tags: web, coldfusion, symlink

Using the following directory structure on a Solaris 11.3 box running ColdFusion 11. Apache is configured to follow Symbolic links. I have tried using all the following ColdFusion configuration options ( Default order,   Until webroot,  In webroot). The test2.cfm wont grab the #DATASOURCE# from the Application.cfm and so it is undefined.

```
/webroot
    - Application.cfm 
   /dir1 
      /dir2
        /dir3
           -test1.cfm 
        /dir4 (softlink to random directory) 
           -test2.cfm
```

---------Application.cfm-------------

```
<CFSET DATASOURCE = "bob" >
<CFAPPLICATION NAME = "bob_app" SESSIONMANAGEMENT = "YES" >
<CFSET SESSION.USERID = "0" >
```

---------test1/test2.cfm-------------

```
<cfoutput>
The data source name is #DATASOURCE#
</cfoutput>
```

Any Suggestions on how to properly add the symbolic link so that search path includes the Application.cfm in the linked directory parent.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the traversal is getting messed up in the upward recursion because the directory operations are scanning upward from the absolute path of the symlinked directory - which is why symlinks aren't a good pattern for anything traversing up.

I would suggest not using symlinks for any directories which are extensions of the main application - other than static assets.

Alternately, though it's messy and less than ideal, you could just add an `Application.cfm` to those directories and add `<cfinclude template="/Application.cfm"/>` ( or `include "/Application.cfm";` ) in a `<cfscript>` block to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Is there anyway to allow coldfusion to do recursion using the symlinked relative path rather then the absolute path? ( Can ColdFusion use the url as means to do reverse traversal)

Comment: At the point at which it starts the upward traversal, looking for an `Application.cfc` or `Application.cfm` it's starting from within the physical directory ( e.g. the symlink ).   If you added an application mapping that matches, the symlink, however, then the mapped path would inherit the scope of the application, when items are invoked or included from within that mapping.

Comment: To clarify, would the mapping be as follows : Logical Path( /webroot/dir1/dir2/dir4)  Directory Path (/real/path/dir4)  or am I misunderstanding